# Polymer core-dropdown value

Tags: html, polymer, web-component

I am using a [core-dropdown](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/elements/core-elements.html#core-dropdown) field in my form along with other core and paper elements. I am able to get values for all inputs but unable to get the value of core-dropdown field on form submit. As per the documentation, there is a `selectedItem` property which can be used to get the selected value but there are no instructions on how to use it.

On a separate note, though I am able to post polymer's paper input fields using [this solution](http://jsbin.com/kurelaji/2/edit) but if there is any other elegant solution for processing forms with polymer, preferably any type of field, e.g. text, radio, checkbox, select, file etc then please share.

Answer (score 0):

The Polymer API is changing rapidly, but currently the way to work with dropdowns and selected items is with the `<core-selector>` [element](https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/elements/core-elements.html#core-selector).

So inside your `core-dropdown`, you would have something like this:

```
<core-selector selected="{{selectedIndex}}">
  <div>Item 1</div>
  <div>Item 2</div>
  <div>Item 3</div>
</core-selector>
```

You can bind to the `selected` attribute which represents either the index of the selected item, or a specific attribute value if `valueattr` is used.

```
Polymer('selector-example', {
    ready: function () {
        this.selectedIndex = 2; // 'Item 3' will be selected
    }
});
```

Unfortunately i'm unable to expand on your solution as the link is broken.

Hope this helps.